# Get total amount of elements in Silverlight RadTreeListView

Tags: silverlight, rad-controls, radtreeview

In Silverlight, I know RadTreeListView.VisibleElements gets me the currently loaded elements on the screen, but for example, if I have 20 elements but only 10 are loaded, I would like to retrieve 20 instead of 10.

The problem is that I do not know how to do this. I would appreciate any help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are you trying to do? You can't get elements which are not created yet. If you need the bound data items, just get them from your model and not from the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I have solved the problem and the solution has been as simple as binding the counter of the list which I am using to load the control.

The problem I am having now is that I have to retrieve the amount of filtered elements in the RadTreeListView. I am searching on the documentation and on the hierarchy's classes, but I do not find anything.